# Embedding PHP server into a C++ Application?

Tags: php, c++, desktop, embed

I need to make web application that is acutely a desktop application
The business logic will be written (taken from web app) in PHP and  the underlain infra is in C++
For that I need some solution to run embed server that support PHP or  to think about some other solution

Comment: I suggest renaming the question more closely to the first sentence. Something like "Using PHP in a desktop application".

Answer (score 0):

You could try [PHP-GTK](http://gtk.php.net/) instead. You can do all the business logic and the presentation in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You could run [Paste Deploy](http://pythonpaste.org/deploy/) as a WSGI container for [WPHP](http://pythonpaste.org/wphp/).

Comment: i dont know the concept of that .. what is it

Answer (score 0):

You can even try Glassfish with Qercus for PHP integration.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Apache as embedded web-server.

Comment: who can i use apache as embedded web server ?

Comment: Try to download XAMP portable Edition. http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646
This allows to embed Apache to your application