# Is there some kind of portable server for running PHP web apps, something like for RoR or Django?

Tags: php, webserver

Currently I'm working on some PHP porjects. And it's a little bit difficult to navigate always through approximately 100 folders to the destination one. Also it's not very comfortable to create virtual hosts for Apache. And it would be much more comfortable to run from CLI command like "someserver start ." and then just go to the localhost:8080 in favorite web-browser and start enjoying the development process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [which server i can embed that support php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932384/which-server-i-can-embed-that-support-php)

Answer (score 6):

If you are thinking along the lines of a built-in server like Mongrel is for Ruby, then No. This doesn't exist for PHP as of PHP 5.3.6. A patch offering that is under discussion though:

> CLI version of PHP will have a new command-line option -S followed by a host address (either in numeric or alphabetic) and a port number delimited by a colon, which will launch a builtin web server listening on the given address and port
>
> ```
> php -S localhost:8000 docroot
> ```

Links:

- [Alexey Zakhlestins on PHP's Webserver](http://blog.milkfarmsoft.com/2011/03/on-phps-webserver)
- [PHP Wiki Request for Comments: Built-in web server](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/builtinwebserver)
- [Webserver Patch](https://gist.github.com/835698)

Answer (score 1):

For a complete self contained web development setup, you can use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). To simplify things further you can then just develop out of the htdoc or www folder provided by xampp.