# Working with PHP offline

Tags: php, offline

Is there a tool or extension for a browser to working with PHP offline? I read about you need to install an Apache server.

Is there an easier way to view offline in browser to see how the PHP code executes?

Comment: If you own a domain, create a subdomain to use for sandbox testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) 
Which are Windows Apache Mysql and Php bundles

In Linux install [LAMP](http://www.lamphowto.com/)
Which is a Linux Apache Mysql and Php bundle

Both of which could help

Comment: Is there a stand-alone tool available for Windows which let me point directly to my PHP file instead of copy everything into the /htdocs/ folder? It seems that Server2Go and XAMPP both want me to copy my files to /htdocs/ which is very impracticable.

Comment: @Michael, why is that `impracticable`?    and if it is, there should be a config to change the public web folder

Comment: Thank you. I found the config.ini file of Server2go and it works now with a custom folder.

Comment: and to try your little code snippets offline, you can try this. https://github.com/vinnizworld/code_editor to

Answer (score 5):

[XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) sets up a local install of MySQL, PHP, and Apache that you can develop on.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, simpler than [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be much use to you **now**, but there has been recent talk (and submission of code) of providing a built-in web server into PHP itself.

See the RFC at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/builtinwebserver

You could then write your script (e.g. `app.php`), execute `php -S localhost:8000` to start the web server and then see the results in your browser at `http://localhost:8000/app.php`.

---

In the mean time, you can install Apache/PHP/MySQL/etc. on your local box, as the other answers have suggested, either manually or with a package like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html).

Comment: I can confirm the built in webserver is included in the current version (php-5.4.7) - unfortunately Ubuntu 12.04 packages version 5.3 (no dice) so you'll have to download and compile from source.

Answer (score 1):

No. PHP code must be processed by a PHP engine, and the easiest way to do so in a web environment is to use a web server. It does not need to be httpd, but it must be [*something*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932384/which-server-i-can-embed-that-support-php).

Answer (score 0):

if you are on a Mac, you have Apache installed already. the additional instructions you will need to add PHP and MySQL database server can be found here http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/

if you are using Windows, XAMPP is a self contained Apache/MySQL/PHP environment that runs as a stand alone application.

that should get you started.  good luck